Error: Only plain objects, and a few builtins can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported
I have created a simple react app to fetch data from an api. Basically it should only display the name of a material given from the api. When I call the api in the browser, it shows the JSON data correctly.
Now when I reload my frontend page the following error message is displayed:
Error: Only plain objects, and a few built-ins, can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported.
at stringify ()
at stringify ()
I created a file called "Material API". Here fetch the data from the API.
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { Material } from "../model/Material";
import { toast } from "sonner";

import { QueryData } from "@/app/model/QueryData";
import error from "next/error";

const fetchMaterial = () => {
  return axios
    .get<Material[]>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/show-data/")
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      toast.error("Error getting material");
      throw error;
    });
};

export const getMaterial = (): QueryData<Material[]> => ({
  queryKey: ["material"],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const response = await fetchMaterial();
    return response.data;
  },
});

The component "MaterialList" will display the data i get from the API.
"use client"

import { getMaterial } from "../api/MaterialApi";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Box, Skeleton, Typography } from "@mui/material";

interface MaterialListProps {}

export const MaterialList: React.FC<MaterialListProps> = () => {
  const { isLoading, data } = useQuery({
    ...getMaterial(),
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });

  return (
    <Box>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Skeleton sx={{ width: "100%" }} />
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data?.map((material) => (
            <li key={material.id}>
              <Typography>{material.name}</Typography>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

I hope somebody can help me with this one.
Tried using an async method but still got the same error.

Try to add "use client" at the top of your MaterialApi file:
"use client"

import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { Material } from "../model/Material";
import { toast } from "sonner";

import { QueryData } from "@/app/model/QueryData";
import error from "next/error";

const fetchMaterial = () => {
  return axios
    .get<Material[]>("http://127.0.0.1:8000/show-data/")
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
      toast.error("Error getting material");
      throw error;
    });
};

export const getMaterial = (): QueryData<Material[]> => ({
  queryKey: ["material"],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const response = await fetchMaterial();
    return response.data;
  },
});

The function getMaterial exported from the file is considered as server side function and when you import it in your client component the provided error appears.
